# iCloud data sharing to all app users

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to know if icloud could be used as a file sharing database for your application amongst all app users or not. If for example in my app you can save a file on icloud, can anyone who uses my app download it or only the person who has uploaded it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iCloud there are no sharing options - only the user who uploaded data can access it.

Comment: This means that I ha to create my own, personal database to use in my app